# Vim command line: last sign color differs

Tags: vim, editor, vi

I am using a slightly modified version of the wombat256 colorscheme. There is this tiny black thing at the end of the command line that drives me crazy.

Does someone know why it doesn't use the command line color and is black instead? As far as I know there is no special color setting for the command line (it should have the same colors as "Normal").

[image: screenshot]

Here is my slightly modified version of the wombat256 color scheme:

```
" Vim color file
" Original Maintainer:  Lars H. Nielsen (dengmao@gmail.com)
" Last Change:  2010-07-23
"
" Converting for 256-color terminals by
" Danila Bespalov (danila.bespalov@gmail.com)
" with great help of tool by Wolfgang Frisch (xororand@frexx.de)
" inspired by David Liang's version (bmdavll@gmail.com)

set background=dark

hi clear

if exists("syntax_on")
    syntax reset
endif

let colors_name = "wombat256fixed"


" General colors
hi Normal       ctermfg=254     ctermbg=234     cterm=none      guifg=#f6f3e8   guibg=#242424   gui=none
hi Cursor       ctermfg=none    ctermbg=241     cterm=none      guifg=NONE      guibg=#656565   gui=none
hi Visual       ctermfg=7       ctermbg=238     cterm=none      guifg=#f6f3e8   guibg=#444444   gui=none
" hi VisualNOS
" hi Search
hi Folded       ctermfg=103     ctermbg=238     cterm=none      guifg=#a0a8b0   guibg=#384048   gui=none
hi Title        ctermfg=7       ctermbg=none    cterm=bold      guifg=#f6f3e8   guibg=NONE      gui=bold
hi StatusLine   ctermfg=7       ctermbg=238     cterm=none      guifg=#f6f3e8   guibg=#444444   gui=italic
hi VertSplit    ctermfg=238     ctermbg=238     cterm=none      guifg=#444444   guibg=#444444   gui=none
hi StatusLineNC ctermfg=243     ctermbg=238     cterm=none      guifg=#857b6f   guibg=#444444   gui=none
hi LineNr       ctermfg=243     ctermbg=234     cterm=none      guifg=#857b6f   guibg=#242424   gui=none
hi SpecialKey   ctermfg=244     ctermbg=236     cterm=none      guifg=#808080   guibg=#343434   gui=none
hi NonText      ctermfg=244     ctermbg=234     cterm=none      guifg=#808080   guibg=#242424   gui=none

" Vim >= 7.0 specific colors
if version >= 700
hi CursorLine                   ctermbg=233     cterm=none                      guibg=#121212
hi MatchParen   ctermfg=7       ctermbg=243     cterm=bold      guifg=#f6f3e8   guibg=#857b6f   gui=bold
hi Pmenu        ctermfg=7       ctermbg=238                     guifg=#f6f3e8   guibg=#444444
hi PmenuSel     ctermfg=0       ctermbg=192                     guifg=#000000   guibg=#cae682
endif


" Syntax highlighting
hi Keyword      ctermfg=111     cterm=none      guifg=#8ac6f2   gui=none
hi Statement    ctermfg=111     cterm=none      guifg=#8ac6f2   gui=none
hi Constant     ctermfg=173     cterm=none      guifg=#e5786d   gui=none
hi Number       ctermfg=173     cterm=none      guifg=#e5786d   gui=none
hi PreProc      ctermfg=173     cterm=none      guifg=#e5786d   gui=none
hi Function     ctermfg=192     cterm=none      guifg=#cae682   gui=none
hi Identifier   ctermfg=192     cterm=none      guifg=#cae682   gui=none
hi Type         ctermfg=192     cterm=none      guifg=#cae682   gui=none
hi Special      ctermfg=194     cterm=none      guifg=#e7f6da   gui=none
hi String       ctermfg=113     cterm=none      guifg=#95e454   gui=italic
hi Comment      ctermfg=246     cterm=none      guifg=#99968b   gui=italic
hi Todo         ctermfg=245     cterm=none      guifg=#8f8f8f   gui=italic


" Links
hi! link FoldColumn     Folded
hi! link CursorColumn   CursorLine

" new setting for current line number
hi CursorLineNr ctermfg=208 ctermbg=233   cterm=none    guifg=#FD971F    guibg=#121212   gui=none

" highlight ColorColumn
hi ColorColumn ctermbg=233 guibg=#232323

" vim:set ts=4 sw=4 noet:
```

Comment: oh.... It seems I never wrote such a long command till the end of command line...  my focus is always on the beginning of the line.. :)

Comment: Cannot see your screenshot

Comment: just double checked it - I can see the screenshot right under the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug, that was fixed with [patch 7.4.627](https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/detail?r=c77ef1bf9623d0c7ebd7e011e6ce7a3a12b0bf41)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm on 7.4.617-1 atm, so I will wait until a new package arrives.

Comment: Installed 7.4.663-1 today (arch) and the problem is gone. Thx!